# Should "lost Iotas" questions be closed and redirected to discord?

Tags: discussion

Should questions like this: "[Can I check that my SEED generated the address? Missing coins!](https://iota.stackexchange.com/q/1542/10)"
stay open and be answered or should they be closed as "off-topic" or as "duplicate" of a question that gives you instructions on what you can do, if you've lost Iotas?

Comment: I answered this concrete question since I am not sure that you can easily find the iota-seed-typo-finder in other IOTA StackExchange questions and since it is quite clear which case it has been (IOTA have been transferred just two days ago and there was no snapshot in between).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not suggest to point people to a different platform (like Discord) as the only option. The way of interaction with Discord is quite different (you have to stay in the chat room and wait until somebody answers, or later wade through hundreds of chat answers (when you check back after a day), which is frustrating for some people (like me)). StackExchange works quite well with posting a question and checking the next day for an answer (and also it makes it feasible for people like me who only have a few hours time per day to find unanswered questions and answer them easily). I assume that if people prefer chat and instant support and to filter the answers themselves, they can find Discord on their own. But if you disagree, feel free to point to the Discord option as well in your answers/comments.

On the other hand, I think it would be a good idea to write up a canonical question/answer "My wallet shows zero funds" which lists all the common causes ordered by how recent your funds are and likelyhood (addresses need reattaching due to snapshot, not enough addresses reattached, mistyped seed, reclaim because of address reuse, reclaim because of signature change and not transitions, funds stolen due to leaked seed / online seed generator, funds stolen due to key reuse) with suggestions how to fix them if possible (and giving a timeframe how long it takes e.g. to get a reclaim processed).

In fact, this was on my todo list as well but I did not find time to do so by now.

If there was such an answer (or did anybody already create one?) we could close most cases as duplicate easily.

Comment: Like a wiki post?

Comment: I totally endorse @mihi proposal. In addition I think that there are a few other topics/questions that periodically appear and to which I would apply a similar approach: a comprehensive answer and duplicate marking.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with any redirects to other sites. If there is already an answer that fully answers any and all cases of "lost funds" questions, then you can redirect to that answer and mark it as duplicate.

If such an answer isn't yet made, let's make one. Until then, answer the specific thing that is being asked, as something is hardly a "duplicate" or "off-topic" if there is no answer for the same question yet and the question is related to iota.

In no way should you have a question on stackoverflow, and the answer not being present on the same page (so, the answer should actually be in the answer, and not in a hyperlink or discord server or anything of the sort).